# Groovy string in sql.firstRow()

Tags: postgresql, groovy

This works:

```
def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
def name = "Introduction"
sql.firstRow("select id from topic where name = ?", [name])
```

While this does not:

```
def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
def name = "Introduction"
sql.firstRow("select id from topic where name = ?", ["$name"])
```

It throws the error - `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.`

Comment: maybe it is just an example, but why would you prefer `"$name"` over simply `name`?

Comment: I don't. It's just an example. Can it be a groovy bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
sql.firstRow("select id from topic where name = ?", ["$name".toString()])
```

Comment: Hmm. I would like to understand why we have to call toString() on a string itself. I do have the solution already by not using a groovy string, just want to understand this.

Comment: it's simple: the java classes sometimes (as with postgress driver here) fail to recognize the fact that GStringImpl is a String, especially if used for type discovery.

Comment: To be clear, GStringImpl is NOT a String... and that's why it can't recognize it.